# Python append list with raw iterator

Tags: python, list, iterator, append

So with the help of StackOverflow I was able to get leaps ahead an for that I'm thankful.

Sadly, I've hit another snag and  I was again hoping I could count on the collective for a little guidance.

To make a long story short, I'm practically merging two list (in Python 2.7) as follows, using the **ration** variable putting (in this case 2) 2 of list 1 and 1 of list 2:

```
ration = 2
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
iter_list1 = iter(list1)
iter_list2 = iter(list2)

final = []
try: #broken when one of the iterators runs out (and StopIteration is raised)
    while True:
        for i in range(0,ratio):
            final.append(next(iter_list1))
        final.append(next(iter_list2))
except StopIteration:
    pass
print(final)
```

Sadly, it's 100% sure that list1 in my case will be far longer than list2, so there will be a StopIteration except error raised, and I'm hoping that I can copy [duplciate if you will] list2 until list1 runs out.

To give you a concrete example: in this case it would work and be:

```
['one', 'two', 'A', 'three', 'four', 'B', 'five']
```

But if the list1 becomes much bigger (lets say list1 holds up until 20) it will run, six - 20 will be left on list1. The disired result would be:

```
['one', 'two', 'A', 'three', 'four', 'B', 'five', six, 'C', 'seven', 'eight', 'A', 'nine', 'ten', 'B', .... ]
```

Any idea on how to proceed?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what would be the desired result?

Comment: Why you are doing two times - "final.append(next(iter_list1))" ? Share final output what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to take two items from `list1` for each item in `list2`.

You can achieve this by zipping your iterators together:

```
>>> list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
>>> list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> it1 = iter(list1)
>>> it2 = iter(list2)
>>> 
>>> zip(it1, it1, it2)
[('one', 'two', 'A'), ('three', 'four', 'B')]
```

`zip` will get the next element from each of its arguments in a round-robin fashion. In this particular case, the first two arguments are the same, so we get two elements from `list1` and then proceed to get an element from `list2`.

`zip` will stop extracting elements from the iterators as soon as it faces a `StopIteration` exception. If you want it to keep going and use a default value for ehausted iterators, take a look at `itertools.izip_longest` (or `itertools.zip_longest` in Python 3).

edit in response to your desired output: you need to flatten the result. This can be done with `itertools.chain` or a list comprehension.

```
>>> it1, it2 = iter(list1), iter(list2)
>>> [x for tup in zip(it1, it1, it2) for x in tup]
['one', 'two', 'A', 'three', 'four', 'B']

>>> it1, it2 = iter(list1), iter(list2)
>>> list(chain(*zip(it1, it1, it2)))
['one', 'two', 'A', 'three', 'four', 'B']
```

Comment: Will this still not cut off list1 as soon as list2 runs out? Essentually, how can I keep using list2 until list1 runs out?

Comment: @user5740843 as I said, use `itertools.izip_longest`.

Answer (score 1):

Itertools?

```
import itertools
x = itertools.izip_longest(list1,list2) #x is a generator
x_list = [i for i in x] #Returns list of tuples
x_flattened_list = [j for i in x_list for j in i]
```

This adds None when list2 runs out. Fill it with required value by using fillvalue parameter in izip_longest.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest